# SWT - ImageRegistry key already in use: org.eclipse.jface.TOOLTIP_CLOSE_ICON

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

When I tried to open tooltip which contain image on one tab it works, but when I switch to other tab I am getting error.
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ImageRegistry key already in use.**

```
JFaceResources.getImageRegistry().put(ControlVerifierToolTip.HEADER_CLOSE_ICON,
               ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(ControlsVerifierView.class, CLOSE_PNG));
```

How to properly configure ImageRegistry?

Comment: You can't replace an existing key if the image (rather than the image descriptor) associated with the key has been created. So you need to arrange to only do the `put` once - maybe a static initializer somewhere.

Comment: @greg-449 How can I reuse the same key it is already open ?

Comment: You `put` things in the registry once and then use `get(key)` or `getDescriptor(key)` to retrieve the image whereever you want to use it.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks static block seems to solve my problem :) appreciate you inputs